# How to configure CVS server in windows for eclipse ...?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I would like to configure CVS server in my workplace for eclipse  development. Please give the steps to configure the CVS server in windows.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Also http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this URL ?

http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/cvs-eclipse-setup.html